# Is Opa's native database and server still available?

Tags: opa

I tried out Opa a couple of years ago.  At that time you could compile an Opa program down to a single executable that contained the server and database.  Coming from a desktop application programming background, I really found this single executable very appealing.

Fast-forward to present.  I started looking at Opa again and now I see that it requires node.js and mongoDB on the server side.  Is it still possible to create a "classic" Opa application which is just one executable containing the server and database as it was a couple of years ago as an option or has that been completely deprecated?  (and if that possibility has been completely eliminated could it be brought back as an option?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Opa native backend has been removed from the open source version.

Comment: Too bad they didn't leave that in as an option.

Comment: I noticed the other day that when you start a new app, it automatically downloads and starts mongodb if necessary (at least on my platform). It's a nice touch for getting up and running quickly.

You still have to install node though.